# on every api call on db, gorm scope keep adding to previous one

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

Below is my api handler.
On first run it gives me correct output and corresponding call in db is also correct.

```
2020-07-04 14:51:04.512 IST [32129] postgres@postgres LOG:  execute <unnamed>: SELECT count(*) FROM "access_owners"  WHERE ("access_owners"."area" = $1)
2020-07-04 14:51:04.512 IST [32129] postgres@postgres DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '4th Floor'
2020-07-04 14:51:04.513 IST [32129] postgres@postgres LOG:  execute <unnamed>: SELECT * FROM "access_owners"  WHERE ("access_owners"."area" = $1) LIMIT 10 OFFSET 2
2020-07-04 14:51:04.513 IST [32129] postgres@postgres DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '4th Floor'
```

this is the API response I get

```
{
    "skip": 2,
    "limit": 10,
    "total": 3,
    "resources": [
        {
            "id": 26,
            "name": "Test_User_5",
            "email": "test_user_5@gmailcom",
            "area": "4th Floor"
        }
    ]
}
```

But if I call the same API again with the same parameters it errors out adding one more where condition in DB.

```
2020-07-04 14:51:22.560 IST [32129] postgres@postgres LOG:  execute <unnamed>: SELECT count(*) FROM "access_owners"  WHERE ("access_owners"."area" = $1) AND ("access_owners"."area" = $2) LIMIT 10 OFFSET 2
2020-07-04 14:51:22.560 IST [32129] postgres@postgres DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '4th Floor', $2 = '4th Floor'
```

And this the error I get

```
sql: no rows in result set
```

This is my API handler

```
func GetAccessOwners(db *gorm.DB) echo.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c echo.Context) error {
        page := new(models.ResourcePage)
        var ao = new(models.AccessOwner)
        var err error
        if err = c.Bind(ao); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        var skip int
        var limit int
        skipParam := c.QueryParam("skip")
        limitParam := c.QueryParam("limit")
        if strings.TrimSpace(skipParam) != "" {
            skip, err = strconv.Atoi(skipParam)
            if err != nil {
                return merry.Wrap(err)
            }
        } else {
            skip = 0
        }

        if strings.TrimSpace(limitParam) != "" {
            limit, err = strconv.Atoi(limitParam)
            if err != nil {
                return merry.Wrap(err)
            }
        } else {
            limit = 10
        }
        accessOwners := []models.AccessOwner{}
        page.Resources = []models.AccessOwner{}
        page.Skip = skip
        page.Limit = limit
        

        db = db.Scopes(GetCount(*ao)).Model(page.Resources).Count(&page.Total)
        db = db.Offset(skip)
        db = db.Limit(limit)
        if err := db.Find(&accessOwners).Error; err != nil {
            return merry.Wrap(err)
        }

        page.Resources = accessOwners
        return c.JSON(201, page)

    }
}

func GetCount(ao models.AccessOwner) func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
    return func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
        return db.Where(ao)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [doc](https://gorm.io/docs/method_chaining.html#Multiple-Immediate-Methods)

> When using multiple immediate methods with GORM, later immediate
> method will reuse before immediate methods’s query conditions

You are setting `db` that's why in the second request query condition of first request already exists in `db`.

```
db = db.Scopes(GetCount(*ao)).Model(page.Resources).Count(&page.Total)
db = db.Offset(skip)
db = db.Limit(limit)
```

So, don't set `db` rather you can do chaining multiple operations or use separately

```
db.Scopes(GetCount(*ao)).Model(page.Resources).Count(&page.Total)
                   .Offset(skip).Limit(limit).Find(&accessOwners)
```

Comment: Thank you @Eklavya . You correctly pointed out the mistake that i was doing. It worked fine after I implemented your suggestion.